# Ignore schema in MySQL dump

Tags: mysql, import, export, schema

Is there a way to restrict/not include multiple schema from the mysqldump command?
Here is my script

```
mysqldump -h localhost -u username -p > database_schema.sql
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

`--no-create-info` is an option you can provide to the `mysqldump` program.

Comment: are you sure, `--no-create-info` look correct based on what im reading.

Comment: Yep, that is correct. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is from `mysqldump --help`:

```
Dumping structure and contents of MySQL databases and tables.
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
```

If you're trying to dump only one database, then you can just specify that as the last parameter of the call. This dumps a database named "happy"

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPassword happy
```

If you want more than one database use the `--databases` flag. This dumps two databases, one named happy, the other named "joy_joy"

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPassword --databases happy joy_joy
```

If you'd like all databases, then specify `--all-databases`. This command would give you happy, joy_joy, and whatever other DBs are on your server.

```
mysqldump -uroot -pPassword --all-databases
```

As far as I know, the only way to restrict the number of tables in a `mysqldump` is by using the `mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]` option.

Comment: What If I want to dump all databases except for happy and joy_joy. Is there an ignore script to exclude this two database schema?

Comment: No, but it wouldn't be that difficult to create one automatically.